# React native custom UI component with Swift: how to access reactTag in event

Tags: react-native

When creating a custom UI component in Swift, how does one access the `reactTag` to trigger an event back to React Native?

Using the following code to create a custom component in Swift that has a button:
When the button is clicked, using the `bridge.eventDispatcher` to `sendInputEventWithName` should raise an event in the React Native JavaScript code.
This is done by passing the reactTag as part of the event dictionary.
However, it is not clear to me how to access the reactTag property, or even where it's available.

(Digging around a bit it seems like it's present on something called `RCTShadowView` however the reactTag is always `nil` on my shadowView)

### Swift

```
//  FooView.swift
import UIKit


@objc(FooView)
class FooView: UIView {
    @objc var bridge: RCTBridge!

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 244, height: 244))
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject?) {
        let event = [
            "target": "", // <-- how can one get access to the reactTag property?
        ]

        self.bridge.eventDispatcher.sendInputEventWithName("topChange", body: event)
    }
}
```

### Objective C

```
//  FooViewBridge.m

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#import "FooProj-Swift.h"


@interface RCTFooViewManager : RCTViewManager
@end


@implementation RCTFooViewManager


RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
    FooView* fooView = [[FooView alloc] init];
    fooView.bridge = self.bridge;
    fooView.shadowView = self.shadowView; // <-- was hoping this would have a reactTag but it's always nil
    return fooView;
}


@end
```

Comment: Did you get how to get/set reactTag?

Comment: I did not. What I ended up doing instead was using `self.bridge.eventDispatcher.sendAppEventWithName("buttonClicked", body: ["button": "foo"])`. It's clearly not as elegant as if we had the tag, but it makes it possible to at least identify the event and listen to it.

Comment: @Jones could you provide a github repo of your example? I think this could help me out

Answer (score 2):

`FooView.swift` needs to be able to see `self.reactTag`, which is declared in `UIView+React.h`.

This needs to be added to the project's `Bridging-Header.h`.

```
#import "UIView+React.h"
```

Side note: you'll probably not be wanting to use `sendInputEventWithName` directly, but using a Swifty variant of the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36031827/4737)

Comment: If you're using Objective-C than use `#import <React/UIView+React.h>`